# Best Buy API call limits

Tags: best-buy-api

what is BestBuy API call limit for the product details? How many calls per hour/day ?

Answer (score 4):

The default call limits for approved accounts is 5 queries per second/50,000 queries per day. If you surpass these limits, you will receive a 429 error code with an error response stating quota limit exceeded.

Comment: looks like technically the limit is different, since i am getting 429 having less than 5 queries  per second and not reaching 50, 000 quota a day, short log just before getting 429:
    

`2017-02-11 11:52:14.131968384 +0000 UTC  API call on product SKU  6900472  
2017-02-11 11:52:14.761974285 +0000 UTC  API call on product SKU  6900667  
2017-02-11 11:52:15.391995526 +0000 UTC  API call on product SKU  6900385  
2017-02-11 11:52:16.041078842 +0000 UTC  API call on product SKU  6900588  
2017-02-11 11:52:16.6825007 +0000 UTC  API call on product SKU  6900658`

Comment: please advice on this matter

Comment: Can you send an email to developer@bestbuy.com with the query you are using against the api, from the email account you used to register your key?  That will give me a lot more information to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone who runs across this question the error code has changed to 403.  Source: https://bestbuyapis.github.io/api-documentation/#errors

Comment: That’s not true; I still get 429s.

Answer (score 1):

The default call limits for approved accounts is 5 queries per second or 50,000 queries per day. If you go pass this limits, you will receive an error code with an error response saying that you have exceeded the quota limit. The error code number is 429.